# linq SubmitChanges method isn't working

Tags: linq

I am using a simple code as follows:

```
        DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        order oder = context.orders.Single(p => p.order_no == 3);

        oder.ship_to_name = "test rana";
        context.SubmitChanges();
```

However data isn't saving to sqlserver db. What have i missed? I have been trying [basic linq tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)

Regards

Comment: what is the data type of `ship_to_name` in your database? any exception did you get when submitting?

Comment: Its string type. No, no exception occured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the orders table have a primary key?
If not, then you wouldn't be able to perform updates.

Comment: Great catch. Yes, it was the situation, Thanks :D